# Collect crash .dmp and .hdmp files after a crash of C++ service and a user-mode app

Tags: c++, winapi, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I'm coding in C++/MFC using WinAPIs. My software consists of a local service and a user-mode app that provides user interface for a logged in Windows user. I'm looking for a way to collect .dmp and .hdmp files in case of crash in either of those modules. I know that [WER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513641%28v=vs.85%29) supposedly collects them and submits them to Microsoft. Is there a way to collect those files and keep them somewhere on the hard drive?

PS. I need this to work under Windows XP SP3, Vista, 7, 8.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: please see my reply below.

Comment: @Deanna: I posted an answer to my own question, the solution that worked for me, but then someone deleted it. So, I said, OK if my solution is not needed for this community, so be it ...

Comment: "someone"? Was the ansert the same as the others posted?

Answer (score 3):

Windows 2000 and XP already save crash dumps using DrWatson. Running `drwtsn32.exe` allows you to get/configure the path to the log and the dump files.

Windows Vista+ only uses WER, which doesn't save a dump by default, but you can [enable creation of user mode dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
I set the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\DumpType` value to 2 to save full dumps which, by default are stored in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps` (`C:\Users\dee.earley\AppData\Local\CrashDumps`).

Installing a debugger like [WinDebug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) will also allow you to catch exceptions from user mode apps and the service as they occur.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's DebugDiag tool is quite useful for monitoring processes and spitting out dump files on exceptions and crashes.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798

I've used this in multiple customer environments to track down problems that I could not reproduce in my own environment.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So how exactly does one use it? Does it mean that I have to install something on a customer's machine to be able to debug it remotely?

Comment: Yes, you have to install and configure this on a customer's machine. You don't get to debug, but you do get a directory full of crash dumps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking a way for handling crash on customers side the best solution is using google-breakpad library. In your case exception handler will write dump files on the disk.