# debug php-cgi.exe + vb6 dll

Tags: php, debugging, vb6

I'm calling through php a vb6 .dll (IIS) and on some rare and weird occasions when i call a particular function the php-cgi.exe crashes with message:

**the instruction 0x029b7387 referenced memory at "0x0f138000". The memory could not be written. Click OK to terminate, click cancel to debug**

the memory address might slightly change but always ends in 8000.

Is there any way to debug and find out what is wrong with my .dll ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try getting a stack/memory dump to see if the call stack gives anything meaningful. That sort of error is crying out as either corrupt memory or using freed memory. Both are difficult to do accidentally in VB6.

Comment: I suspect the error is not produced by the vb6 dll, but by underlying dlls in C, which get called from the vb6 dll. how do i get the stack/memory dump ?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11479571/588306) on how to configure user mode memory dumps. I'm not sure if that will catch exceptions in a service though.